# Обсчет игры, пока она была выключена

Tags: unity3d

Часто в мобильных стратегиях бывает.

Задал строительство здания. И вышел.
Зашел через какое-то время. Оно уже построилось. Так же с добычей ресурсов.

Вопрос как такое можно реализовать? Какие есть возможности?

Само состояние можно сохранить через серриализацию класс и сохранить это. А после восстановить всю сцену со всеми переменными на момент закрытия игры, это понятно.

Далее как за прошедший момент обсчитать все, что должно было произойти.

Самое просто, что приходить в голову. Это взять время на момент закрытия и время на момент нового запуска игры. А затем от количества секунд обсчитать. Что должно было произойти.

Но если такой расчет сделать сложно.

Есть предприятия и транспорт который возит грузы между предприятиями.

Каждое предприятие циклично(независимо) совершает производство: потребляют ресурсы и что-то производят(но только если есть ресурсы).

А транспорт, независимо от циклов предприятий, перевозит груз. Забирает груз, если есть на предприятии и везет за t времени(в зависимисти от расстояния и скорости каждого транспорта) груз на другое предприятие.

Как доп условие. Возможно, что транспорт не сразу выезжает с предприятия если ему мешает другой транспорт.

Наверное можно составить некий класс, вроде мат. модели. Куда загонять все исходные данные и все в нем обсчитывать. Но это очень трудоемко. И при некоторых исходных данных и нереально.

Может существуют иные способы реализации данной задачи? О которых я не знаю.

Comment: Пока игрок не видит можно значительно упростить симуляцию, в самом простом случае - просто по прошедшему времени начислить ресурсы/баллы (можно подмешать рандом). Все зависит от правил игры.

Comment: Первое что бы я не стал в вашем случаи делать, это отсчитывать и подсчитывать на закрытие и открытие игры. Делайте все это на стороне сервера. Т.е POST запрос - на строительство с серверных временем. GET запрос на отрисовку и расчёт всех ресурсов при открытии игры.  В вашем случае игра должна только читать и посылать запросы (вы их обрабатываете на сервере и выводите результат «true/false и тд»). Иначе много будет «хитрых» игроков.

Comment: @Insider, я понимаю о чем вы говорите. Но это уже немного более сложный класс игры. К нему нужен другой подход. Да и средства, хотя бы на сервер. Что бы выдерживал нагрузку и все обсчитывал. Это уже больше клиент/серверное приложение. А вот время брать с сервера, это конечно можно.

Comment: Слегка не правильно написал или вы не докца меня поняли. Вы сохраняете время на сервере по времени сервера. Далее при открытом или открытии приложение, получаете время и по нему считаете, только не сравнивайте с временем приложения.

Comment: А, понял. Да так можно. Да брать время с сервера надежнее.

Answer (score 0):

создай немного упрощенную модель имитации игры (для такого я когда-то изучал что-то вроде графов работ, похожее есть в MS Project)
по диаграмме можно определить какой процесс - "слабое место" и какое минимальное время выполнения
можешь создать службу, но крайне не советую нагружать ее логикой игры.
максимум - добавь в нее показ уведомления в вычисленное время

Comment: @Vladimir, хорошую мысль подал. Упростить какие то детали игры, при обсчете. В большом массиве данных, я думаю погрешность сгладится.

И я с вами согласен. Необходимо построить модель игры. Как сказал, Vladimir, упрощенную. Сама модель должна наверное уже быть построена по тому, что требуется в конкретном случае. 
Как лучше это реализовать, это вопрос наверное уже более узкий.